# Python xmlns register_namespace

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces, elementtree

I am trying to read a xml modify some tags and print in output, but python add "NS0" and "NS1" in output file. i did some tests and removed "NS0" but i could not remove "NS1". input XML bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<nfeProc versao="3.10" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
    <NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
        <infNFe versao="3.10" Id="NFe53171205246123000120650010000000011152346962">
            <ide>
                <cUF>53</cUF>
            </ide>
            <emit>
                <CNPJ>05246123000120</CNPJ>
                <xNome>TESTE</xNome>
                <xFant>TESTE</xFant>
            </emit>
            <det nItem="1">
                <prod>
                    <cProd>1</cProd>
                    <cEAN/>
                    <xProd>USING</xProd>
                    <NCM>12333</NCM>
                    <comb>
                        <cProdANP>23333111</cProdANP>
                        <UFCons>DF</UFCons>
                        <encerrante>
                            <nBico>20</nBico>
                            <nBomba>5</nBomba>
                            <nTanque>6</nTanque>
                            <vEncIni>1503366.039</vEncIni>
                            <vEncFin>1503368.540</vEncFin>
                        </encerrante>
                    </comb>
                </prod>
            </det>
        </infNFe>
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
                <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                <Reference URI="#NFe53171205246123000120650010000000011152346962">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <DigestValue>LZ5vw12GA+Iqp7h94N3UyuWmzKQ=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>asdsd</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
                <X509Data>
                    <X509Certificate>asd321321</X509Certificate>
                </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
        </Signature>
    </NFe>
</nfeProc>
```

The code is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

hashBico = {};
hashTanque = {};

with open('bin\\de_para_bico.txt', 'rU') as fIn:
    for line in fIn.readlines():
        line.strip();
        splited = line.split(';');

        CNPJ = re.sub("\D", "", splited[2]);
        bicoAntigo = splited[3];
        bicoNovo = splited[5].strip();
        hashBico[CNPJ, bicoAntigo] = bicoNovo;
fIn.close();

with open('bin\\de_para_tanque.txt', 'rU') as fIn:
    for line in fIn.readlines():
        line = line.strip();
        splited = line.split(';');

        CNPJ = re.sub("\D", "", splited[2]);
        tanqueAntigo = splited[3];
        tanqueNovo = splited[5];
        hashTanque[CNPJ, tanqueAntigo] = tanqueNovo;
fIn.close();

with open('bin\\filelist.txt', 'rU') as fIn:
    for line in fIn.readlines():    
        arq = 'entrada\\'+line.strip();
        with open(arq, 'rU') as fInArq:
            # for lineArq in fInArq.readlines():
            lineArq = fInArq.read();
            lineArq=lineArq.strip();

            # ET.register_namespace('', "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
            ET.register_namespace('', "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe");

            tree = ET.parse(arq);
            root = tree.getroot();

            tag = '{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}'
            seacher = '{}NFe/{}infNFe/{}det/{}prod/{}comb/{}encerrante'.format(tag, tag, tag, tag, tag, tag)
            CNPJ = root.find('{}NFe/{}infNFe/{}emit/{}CNPJ'.format(tag, tag, tag, tag));

            for item in root.findall(seacher):
                nBico = '{}nBico'.format(tag);
                nTanque = '{}nTanque'.format(tag);

                item.find(nBico).text   = hashBico[CNPJ.text, item.find(nBico).text];
                item.find(nTanque).text = hashTanque[CNPJ.text, item.find(nTanque).text];

                # print(CNPJ.text, item.find(nBico).text  );
                # print(CNPJ.text, item.find(nTanque).text);

            output = arq.replace("entrada", "saida", 1);
            tree.write(output)

        fInArq.close();
fIn.close();
```

As you can see in bellow "ET.register_namespace('', "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe");" removes "NS0:" but still appearing "NS1:" how can i remove this too?

```
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" versao="3.10">
    <NFe>
        <infNFe Id="NFe53171205246123000120650010000000011152346962" versao="3.10">
            <ide>
                <cUF>53</cUF>
            </ide>
            <emit>
                <CNPJ>05246123000120</CNPJ>
                <xNome>TESTE</xNome>
                <xFant>TESTE</xFant>
            </emit>
            <det nItem="1">
                <prod>
                    <cProd>1</cProd>
                    <cEAN />
                    <xProd>USING</xProd>
                    <NCM>12333</NCM>
                    <comb>
                        <cProdANP>23333111</cProdANP>
                        <UFCons>DF</UFCons>
                        <encerrante>
                            <nBico>8</nBico>
                            <nBomba>5</nBomba>
                            <nTanque>2</nTanque>
                            <vEncIni>1503366.039</vEncIni>
                            <vEncFin>1503368.540</vEncFin>
                        </encerrante>
                    </comb>
                </prod>
            </det>
        </infNFe>
        <ns1:Signature>
            <ns1:SignedInfo>
                <ns1:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                <ns1:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                <ns1:Reference URI="#NFe53171205246123000120650010000000011152346962">
                    <ns1:Transforms>
                        <ns1:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                        <ns1:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                    </ns1:Transforms>
                    <ns1:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                    <ns1:DigestValue>LZ5vw12GA+Iqp7h94N3UyuWmzKQ=</ns1:DigestValue>
                </ns1:Reference>
            </ns1:SignedInfo>
            <ns1:SignatureValue>asdsd</ns1:SignatureValue>
            <ns1:KeyInfo>
                <ns1:X509Data>
                    <ns1:X509Certificate>asd321321</ns1:X509Certificate>
                </ns1:X509Data>
            </ns1:KeyInfo>
        </ns1:Signature>
    </NFe>
</nfeProc>
```

i have try many different ways incluiding:

```
ET.register_namespace('', "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
ET.register_namespace('', "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe");

tree = ET.parse(arq);
root = tree.getroot();
```

but still appering it.

Comment: Please post your examples as text, not images. We can't help if it's difficult to use your examples

Comment: how can i past xml as a text?

Comment: @LucasMonteiro Just copy and paste. :) Indent as code with Ctrl+K

Comment: it's done, thank you man.

Comment: Maybe you have to switch to `lxml`. `ET.register_namespace()` trick only works for one default namespace, as far as I know, since the underlying storage is a dictionary...

Comment: @har07 How can i change my code? can you show me?

Comment: Install the library, if you haven't already, and follow [the documentation](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html). It has API that is very similar to elementtree, so chances are you don't need to change anything but the `import`, probably you won't even need `ET.register_namespace()` at all (I don't have `lxml` in my current machine to actually verify this)